# Is it possible to invoke a script, when closing a Zsh shell (or the terminal)?

Tags: terminal, zsh

Is it possible to run a script when I close my (Zsh) shell (and/or the terminal emulator)?

I frequently keep an terminal open, with a specific configuration. Before closing it, I'd like to be asked, in order to avoid closing it accidentally (which happens frequently).

The script to check/ask is simple, but I was wondering how to hook it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shell is a login-shell, the file `~/.zlogout` gets executed, so you can put your commands there.

For other cases, you could set up a `trap` command for catching a normal `exit` of the shell, or a signal which may kill your shell. In addition to the usual `trap` command, ZSH allows you to define trap-functions (see the section *Trap Functions* in the **zshmisc** man-page). For example, if you have defined a function named `TRAPEXIT`, it is executed when the shell exits.

I don't know how your terminal program treats the processes it spawns, so if you just close the terminal, I can't say whether it is polite enough to first send a trappable signal, before killing it the hard way.